# Xamarin.android Use axml to create objects dynamically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

My application needs a view with repeating items at the bottom of the screen. There can be more items than screenspace. Therefore I need a HorizontalScrollView (I tried it with a listview and a custom adapter but there is no native way to get a horizontal listview). I want to create the items dynamically.

Now the question is: Can I use my axml (xml?) file to define the structure of my items when I generate them in code?

My xml file consists of a linearlayout with a few textviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a HorizontalScrollView (I tried it with a listview and a custom adapter but there is no native way to get a horizontal listview).

You could use `RcyclerView` to achieve this effect. It did the same work like `ListView` that displays a collection of items in a list or a grid. Here is the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/) about how to use `RecyclerView` in `Xamarin.Android` and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/RecyclerViewer/) is the samle code.

When you want to display items in `Horizontal`, you just need to give your `RecyclerView` a `horizontaLayoutlManager`, code like this :

```
 LinearLayoutManager horizontalManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal,false);
 recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(horizontalManager);
```

> Now the question is: Can I use my axml (xml?) file to define the structure of my items when I generate them in code?

If you use `RecyclerView`, you could inflate the `.axml` when you override the [OnCreateViewHoder](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/#OnCreateViewHolder) method, the `.axml` fine will define the structure of your `RecyclerView` items, code like this :

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
     // Inflate the item for the RecyclerView:
     View itemView = LayoutInflater.From (parent.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.youraxml, parent, false);

     // Create a ViewHolder to hold view references inside the CardView:
     YourViewHolder vh = new YourViewHolder (itemView);
     return vh;
}
```